# GUI_UPLOAD uploads extra null bytes at the end

Tags: abap

I'm using gui_upload to attach a file to email. Gui_upload fills the internal table in hex format. But, always, the last record of internal table is filled with zero '0' until it fits its length.

Think that this is the internal table **(t_mailhex)**;

85020E0368CEE8AEFF98BEF9100800880C2D773CAEEF95C63
5005151AC1FEB1228FBB1F4C68D715468E0934AB24B8799A7
A2B67D3456A8B370FF12578966738CC7805D088A0BAD81DD3
86941AE43776E4F255FF1ED461FE0D9702F596EE0CBD89C2E
492A27EF90500000000000000000000000000000000000000

Like this. The last record has ending zeros. So the file that I attach is not the file I want. It has some weird null character in the place of that zeros.

And that is the function.

```
DATA: t_mailhex   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF solix.

CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_UPLOAD'
    EXPORTING
      filename                = l_file
      filetype                = 'BIN'
    TABLES
      data_tab                = t_mailhex
    EXCEPTIONS
      file_open_error         = 1
      file_read_error         = 2
      no_batch                = 3
      gui_refuse_filetransfer = 4
      invalid_type            = 5
      no_authority            = 6
      unknown_error           = 7
      bad_data_format         = 8
      header_not_allowed      = 9
      separator_not_allowed   = 10
      header_too_long         = 11
      unknown_dp_error        = 12
      access_denied           = 13
      dp_out_of_memory        = 14
      disk_full               = 15
      dp_timeout              = 16
      OTHERS                  = 17.
```

Should a remove those zeros manually or am I missing something using the function ?

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack page started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is the whole solution;

First you need to import the file length to an integer variable.

```
CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload
...
    IMPORTING
    filelength              = fleng_i
...
```

Write it to a character type variable and add **i_attachment_size** as parameter to the class of add attachment;

```
CALL METHOD w_document->add_attachment
EXPORTING
    i_attachment_size  = fleng
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The function works exactly as intended, you're just not using it correctly. You're ignoring the additional parameter that tells you how many bytes were read. Since the lines of your table have a fixed length, it's not technically possible to omit these trailing zeroes. You can concatenate the bytes into an `XSTRING`, but you'll have to keep track of how many bytes you already collected and cut off the trailing zeroes in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wish I know how to find how many bytes were read. By the way, I'm always getting "obsolete function" warning from you. :-)

Comment: @Mtok Then why do you insist on using obsolete and unsupported legacy function modules where a supported alternative exists? As for the file size, the function module `GUI_UPLOAD` has an exporting parameter named `FILELENGTH` that you chose not to use....

Comment: CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES is marked as not released for customer use in my 7.01 system, while GUI_UPLOAD is not marked as obsolete or unsupported.  7.01 is not an ancient system that no one is still running.  You could be a little softer in your responses, IMO.

Comment: @BryanCain You're right - looks like I confused WS_UPLOAD and GUI_UPLOAD.